# C# Task Multithreading Mac M1

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, apple-m1

I came across a strange thing in C# Tasks. I am developing a console application **on windows**, now I wanted to continue working from a computer on an **apple m1** and found that **all my multithreading, written in tasks, does not work on m1 or mac in principle.But its OK on windows**
Is there any way to fix this?

I know that you can rewrite it all on threads, but it's long and sometimes expensive for resources, maybe there is an easier way?)

***UPD:***

```
    public void Run()
    {
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(adress);
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();
        wait = Task.Run(() => WaitingToConnection());
        read = Task.Run(() => ReadAsync());
        ConsoleSend = Task.Run(() => ConsoleSendAsync());
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        work = false;
        wait.Wait();
        read.Wait();
        ConsoleSend.Wait();
        wait.Dispose();
        read.Dispose();
        ConsoleSend.Dispose(); 
        foreach (TcpClient client in clients)
        {
            Send("!bye", client);
            client.Close();
        }
        clients.Clear();
    }





    public async Task WaitingToConnection()
    {
        Task<TcpClient>? x = null;
        TcpClient client;
        int i = 0;
        while (work)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("жду"+i.ToString());//Here 103/0/1
            i++;
            if (x == null)
            {
                x = Task.Run(() => server.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
            }
            if (x.IsCompleted)
            {
                client = x.Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Подключен клиент. " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port);
                clients.Add(client);
                x = null;
            }

        }


    }
```

**I apply the code, wait.Wait() breakpoints; was not called, but at the same time I get 103 in the waiting cycle and then nothing, either only 1 or nothing**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Normally it is best that you post an example. That makes it easier for anyone to help you and for people in the future to get help from you question.

Comment: Post a simple example of some task based code that doesn't work.  I'm guessing there is a bug in your code that doesn't manifest itself in Windows, but on a Mac, it does.

Comment: Ah ha, you aren't using Tasks 'properly'.  All those `Task.Run` are not how you use async/await.  Rule of thumb, if you have an async method (like `AcceptTcpClientAsync`), you should use `await`.